# Cómo sacar los 5 números mayores de un vector en JAVA

Tags: java, vectores

Estoy trabada en la segunda parte de este ejercicio: "En un vector de 23 posiciones se tienen las temperaturas máximas de las capitales de las 23 provincias argentinas en el último mes. A partir de esta información, un noticiero desea determinar el top 5 de las temperaturas más altas para poder mostrar en la pantalla de su programa, para ello se necesita un programa que sea capaz de recorrer el vector de temperaturas, determinar las 5 más altas y copiarlas en un nuevo vector de 5 posiciones". Cómo sacaría el top 5?
Hasta ahora este es el cógido que tengo:

```
  public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] temperaturas = new int [23];
      Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);
      for (int i=0; i<23; i++) {
      System.out.print("Ingrese las temperaturas: " + i);
      int tecla = teclado.nextInt();
       temperaturas[i] = tecla;       
   }
   }
   }
```

Comment: Una posible solución en 3 líneas https://onlinegdb.com/04cgKa_wu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se muestran dos soluciones diferentes. La primera es la propuesta por Jaime en los comentarios, haciendo uso de [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html); la segunda hace uso de la clase [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html).

Como se puede observar ambos métodos hacen sort del arreglo y toman los primeros 5 elementos; sin embargo, el segundo método afecta al arreglo original.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer[] temperatures = new Integer[23];
        Arrays.setAll(temperatures, (x)-> (int) (Math.random() * 80 - 10));

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(temperatures));

        //////////////
        // Método 1
        //////////////

        Integer[] top5 = Arrays.stream(temperatures)
                .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                .limit(5)
                .toArray(Integer[]::new);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(top5));

        //////////////
        // Método 2
        //////////////

        Arrays.sort(temperatures, Comparator.reverseOrder());
        Integer[] otherWay = Arrays.copyOfRange(temperatures, 0, 5);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(otherWay));

    }
}
```

**Nota:** Las clases como `Integer, Double, Float, etc` tienen implementada la interfaz Comparable, por lo cual cuentan con un orden natural (ascendente), por eso se usa [Comparator#reverseOrder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#reverseOrder()) para lograr un ordenamiento descendiente.

## Manualmente

Probablemente como sigues aprendiendo el uso de funciones lambda no es adecuado, por lo cual posiblemente prefieras el método 2.

Pero si quieres hacerlo desde 0, sin usar ninguna clase, lo que puedes hacer es implementar tu propio método de ordenamiento. En geeksforgeeks tienen [tutoriales](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-algorithms/) muy buenos de diversos métodos.